# How to create a pytest fixture that is a list of other fixtures in the test session

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-fixtures

I have a use case where I have some code that needs iterate over a family of fixtures and execute a common set of operations upon each fixture value. Right now I'm handling it with statically defined lists that I'm pushing off to plugins but this is somewhat tedious. I'd like to instead have some dynamic means of populating the list of fixtures. Here's a snippet of a static creation of the `fix_list` fixture where I hardcode the list of other fixtures I know in advance I wish to be part of the list...

```py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def fix_foo():
    print("fix_foo")
    return "foo"

@pytest.fixture
def fix_fiz_foo():
   print("fix_fiz_foo")
   return "fiz_foo"

@pytest.fixture
def fix_other():
    print("fix_other")
    return "other"

@pytest.fixture
def fix_other2():
    print("fix_other2")
    return "other2"

def test_foo(fix_list):
    assert not fix_list

@pytest.fixture
def fix_list(fix_foo, fix_fiz_foo)
    return [fix_foo, fix_fiz_foo]
```

How could I populate `fix_list` dynamically at runtime without this static connection to other fixtures?

Acceptable solutions would be me being able to select by fixture name where I impose a naming convention like the example above where each fixture name ends with `"_foo"` in its identifier, or I could go by the fixture value type even or some attribute present in its value with some distinct attribute value I could test against.

---

### Failed Attempt:

I've tried snooping around the fixture manager but I'm finding the `cached_result` is always `None` because this fixture holds no explicit reference to any other fixture in its function signature. When I actually statically reference a desired fixture then the `cached_result` gets populated but that defeats the purpose of tackling variability across different test projects I'm trying to juggle and avoid writing all the static combinations I'm having to face.

Here's my attempt and the shortcoming's I'm hitting a dead end on...

```py
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def fix_list(request):
    print("fix_list")
    foo_fixtures = [fix_name for fix_name in request._fixturemanager._arg2fixturedefs if fix_name.endswith("_foo")]

    for fix_name in foo_fixtures:
        fix_def = request._fixturemanager._arg2fixturedefs[fix_name][0]
        if fix_def.cached_result is None:
            print(f"fix_name = {fix_name}, null cached_result")
        else:
            print(f"fix_name = {fix_name}, cached_result = {fix_def.cached_result}")
```

executing this test module yields the following output

```
$ pytest  -s test_proj/test_module.py
============================================== test session starts ============================================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.13, pytest-7.0.1, pluggy-1.2.0
rootdir: /home/USERX/test_proj
plugins: order-1.0.1, dependency-0.5.1, depends-1.0.1, anyio-3.7.1, rerunfailures-10.1, metadata-3.0.0, json-report-1.4.1, pytest_check-1.0.5
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                                                   

test_proj/test_module.py fix_list
fix_name = fix_fiz_foo, null cached_result
fix_name = fix_foo, null cached_result
.

=============================================
```

I can see the two fixtures are filtered by name, but I have no `cached_result` to produce a list with any meaningful values. I hope I'm not crashing into some pytest design limitation trying to tease out these dynamic lookups. There's a bit of a chicken and egg scenario with this cached_results I'm hoping I'm just missing something that I can do to hatch the egg and get access to it without referencing it statically anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Just got lucky snooping around the `hook_spec.py` [source](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/d2b214220f63e1fc90120495d600893cfba6219f/src/_pytest/hookspec.py#L619-L625), which referenced an interesting callback `pytest_fixture_setup`. I then searched and found a hit in my repo where someone used `pytest_fixture_setup`, and within it I noticed they did `request.getfixturevalue` and I then prototyped and realized this deferred lookup `getfixturevalue` does the trick!

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def fix_list(request):
    print("fix_list")
    foo_fixtures = [request.getfixturevalue(fix_name) for fix_name in request._fixturemanager._arg2fixturedefs if fix_name.endswith("_foo")]
    return foo_fixtures
```

changing the test case to the following

```
def test_foo(fix_list):
    assert not fix_list
```

now gives this output

```
$ python3.8 -m pytest  -s test_proj/test_module.py
=========================== test session starts =============================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.13, pytest-7.0.1, pluggy-1.2.0
rootdir: /home/USERX/test_proj


----------


plugins: order-1.0.1, dependency-0.5.1, depends-1.0.1, anyio-3.7.1, rerunfailures-10.1, metadata-3.0.0, json-report-1.4.1, pytest_check-1.0.5
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

test_proj/test_module.py fix_list
fix_fiz_foo
fix_foo
F

============================== FAILURES =================================================================
_____________________________________ test_foo __________________________________________________________________

fix_list = ['fiz_foo', 'foo']

    def test_foo(fix_list):
>       assert not fix_list
E       AssertionError: assert not ['fiz_foo', 'foo']

test_proj/test_module.py:32: AssertionError
==================================================================== short test summary info =========================================================================================================
FAILED test_proj/test_module.py::test_foo - AssertionError: assert not ['fiz_foo', 'foo']
======================================================================= 1 failed in 0.06s =============================================================================
```